# Why does docker list two separate images (one of which doesn't exist) for my container?

Tags: docker

I have what I believe to be an extremely odd situation: 'docker ps' reports that my container is running an image which does not exist. 'docker inspect mycontainer' gives the image hash of an image that DOES exist, but that hash is not the image named in the .config.image node in the inspect output.

`docker inspect mycontainer` gives two different opinions on the image in use:

```
[
    {
        ...
        "Image": "sha256:64c33ae1c7ca7f7838d34505a7ec93e2b8d59e5140f0f5a6974776340cde9d17",
        ...
        "Config": {
            ...
            "Image": "regserver:5000/company/myimage:64",
            ...
        },
       ...
    }
]
```

`docker images` says one of those images exists, and one does not:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> docker images regserver:5000/company/myimage
REPOSITORY                       TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
regserver:5000/company/myimage   60                  fdfbd99e9bcf        2 weeks ago         9.48 GB
regserver:5000/company/myimage   59                  64c33ae1c7ca        2 weeks ago         9.48 GB
regserver:5000/company/myimage   58                  7152dfbe5808        2 weeks ago         9.48 GB
regserver:5000/company/myimage   57                  d2603ae3b3b3        3 weeks ago         9.48 GB
regserver:5000/company/myimage   56                  cff15a634cfb        3 weeks ago         9.48 GB
regserver:5000/company/myimage   55                  b52e8d21fc10        3 weeks ago         9.48 GB
regserver:5000/company/myimage   52                  5e00504b1cf8        3 weeks ago         9.48 GB
regserver:5000/company/myimage   51                  157eef3e8c9e        3 weeks ago         9.48 GB
```

`docker ps` outputs what I believe is incorrect information:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> docker ps --all --format 'table {{.Names}}\t{{.Status}}\t{{.Image}}'
NAMES         STATUS              IMAGE
mycontainer   Up About an hour    regserver:5000/company/myimage:64
```

The hash given by `docker inspect` is the hash of the image regserver:5000/company/myimage:59 but that is not the image that `docker ps` says is in use. The image that `docker ps` says is in use isn't an image that exists.

What gives? Is this a bug in docker (Windows)? Is there something going on here that I just don't understand?

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly conjecture, but it appears that when you created the container, you told Docker to use the image named `regserver:5000/company/myimage:64`, which existed at the time and had a hash of `64c33ae1c7ca...`.  Some time later, this image was untagged and retagged as `regserver:5000/company/myimage:59` (or, less likely, it was untagged, and then you stumbled upon a hash collision).

`docker inspect` shows the original image name under `Config` because that dictionary lists the parameters used to create the container, and it shows the image hash in the top-level `Image` key because `regserver:5000/company/myimage:64` no longer means what it used to so Docker defaults to the hash.

The real question is why `docker ps` shows the old image name; I seem to recall that, in previous Docker versions, untagging an image would cause any containers still using that image to list the image's hash in `docker ps` output.

Comment: I've verified that that's not what happened. Indeed, I can remove the container and recreate the situation at will. I specify the container in the 'docker run' without ever running the 'docker pull' and it ends up with the wrong image. I thought docker would pull the image if it didn't exist?